# Why didn't the explosive device detonate?

Tags: predator-series, predator-2

In Predator 2, the Yautja is seen enabling the explosive device, as he thinks the fall is imminent; then Lieutenant Mike Harrigan, slashed the right arm of the Predator, with the device embedded, causing the alien to fall and use the blades as support to break through a window.

But if the clock was already running, why didn't the device
explode?

Answer (score 3):

Harrigan's cut goes through the middle of the gauntlet, cutting the explosive device in twain.

[image: Image of Harrigan cutting the gauntlet] <sub>click to enlarge</sub>

Presumably, this disrupting the mechanism enough to prevent it from exploding. [This page notes](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/predator/weapons/self-destruct-device/) that

> As the timer counts down, Harrigan manages to use the Smart Disc to sever the Predator’s arm, stopping the device from working. Interestingly, the self-destruct mechanism ceases to function however in *Alien vs Predator*, it is shown that it can be used as a remote explosive not connected to the Predator.

It could be that this is a plot hole, or it could be that the intent was indeed to have the self-destruct sufficiently damaged as to not function (I could see some value in not having an explosive device strapped to one's arm go off because it took a hit).

It's possible that the novelization or the shooting script contains more information, but I don't own a copy of either.

Comment: it's something interesting the info in your answer, but ,arguably, the intended use of the device would indicate that damaging to some extent makes it ignite (with/without the nominal power since it has been damaged). And in the common sense (mine of course!) it's complex to disable these mechanisms and certainly splitting inn half isn't a way to to do so. IMHO, this seems (again to me) a plot hole, but I'm looking in the movies and certain comics (especially the crossovers) and references in games to check it out.

Comment: "the intended use of the device would indicate that damaging to some extent makes it ignite" — does an alien hunter really want the explosive device on their arm to explode if damaged?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, Once it has been activated I think it does.

Comment: @riccs_0x Cool, but even though we’re in magical alien technology world, it could be pretty tricky to design an explosive that won’t normally detonate if damaged, but will after the on-switch has been flicked.